# How to disable dropdown list auto-opening in AutoCompleteTextView when notifyDataSetChanged() called?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, refresh, autocompletetextview

Here's my problem:

In my android app I use AutoCompleteTextView and refresh items list for each 5 seconds. Refreshing is working, when I call notifyDataSetChanged(). But when I type here something and it'll give me the list of matching items and then I close it manually, when another thread is refreshing the list and calling notifyDataSetChanged() dropdown list is showing automatically (even if I closed it before). And it's really annoying, because if list is long it takes whole screen and after closing it'll appear in another 5 secounds.
I tried dismissDropDown() just after calling notifyDataSetChanged(), but it doesn't have any effect. It looks like dropdown is showing with a little delay. It's also not good way to fix it, because if user hasn't closed the list it'll close after a refresh. Also tried to take focus away - still no effect.

So I need a method to:
update my items list (via notifyDataSetChanged()) without automatically showing dropdown list, but if dropdown was already showed don't close it.

Hope you can help,

cheers

---

I did it, finally. I post here a solution, maybe someone will use this.

To check if dropdown is visible:

```
final boolean isVisible = autocomplete.isPopupShowing();
```

Next, call notifyDataSetChanged(),

Finally:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {
    if(!isVisible){
        autocomplete.dismissDropDown();
    }
}

});
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: how you update the automCoplete adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I have also this problem, I think it seems to be a bug, i solved this by the following way

First of all set your AutoCompleteTextView focusable property to false.

Second change your AutoCompleteTextView focusable property to true in onTouch event of that view.For that you have to implement onTouchListener to the AutoCompleteTextview.

Whenever you touching on that AutoCompleteTextView, you should change focusable property to true otherwise keep it focusable to false. So that the dropdown list is never appear when the view is in unfocusable state.

It shows dropdown list automatically, only when the view is in focusable state which is annoying to user, otherwise it works good.